# Slow Clustered index creation in Microsoft SQL (2014)... normal?

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2014

long time lurker here. I have noticed that when creating a unique clustered index on a large data set (200 million records, 30-40 columns) on two columns (Customer ID and Date) that system resources seem to be minimally utilized even though it is an intensive task.

The data is often pre-sorted in a similar or exact order of the index being created however an unsorted data set has similar observations.

a. cpu stays under 3% (32 logical cores, maxdop set to 8)

b. standard sql (parallel index plans not supported)

c. disk utilization often under 1MBS (the disk supports 500+mbs), with bursts for less than 1% of the time over 100mbs

d. network utilization is under 10kbs but supports 1gbs

e. no other processes occuring on sql, 115GB of ram available.

This occurs with indexes created on temp tables or physical tables. Just curious why a lot of system resources are not utilized. Serial non-parallel process possibly that utilizes minimal resources?

server settings:
a. minimum server memory : default 0
b. max server memory 115gb
c. index creation memory 0 (default)
d. minimum memory per query (8192kb, up from 1024kb default)

Utilization of the hint "sort in tempdb" has not had a noticeable effect. Basic logic is being utilized:
"create unique clusterd index abc on test.mydb.mytable (id_column, date_column)"

Thank you for any insight.

unique: Clustered index query plan
insert > clustered index insert (cost 100%) > compute scalar > compute scalar > compute scalar > top > constant scan.

Sometimes a sort will be in there with a share of the cost % if not 100% presorted.

additional info:

when the data is not sorted the index looks like:
insert > index insert (21% cost) > sort (76% cost) > table scan (3% cost)

sort and insert always have a warning:

insert: no explanation for yellow exclamation mark . States maxdop = 1 (only option for sql standard I believe)

sort:  mentions tempdb spill data warning.
"operator used tempdb to spill data during execution with spill level 1 and 1 spilled thread(s), Sort wrote 1826397 pages to and read 1826397 pages from tempddb with granted memory 21016760kb..."

Adding the hint to use the tempdb when creating the index often has adverse effects even though the perfromance of both drives are the same (Sql db drive and the tempdb).

**UPDATE:**
Side note: I often notice queries spilling into the tempdb (8 threads since maxdop = 8) and are granted 12-16GB of memory in the query optimizer. The server has 128GB of ram with 115GB dedicated to SQL. When no other queries are running on the server it still spills over which is odd.

Comment: 3% CPU means one core pegged on a 32 core system, right? So it's bottlenecked on CPU. I find 1MB/s untypically slow, though.

Comment: 97% of the server is idle... is it because its sql standard and parallel index creation is not allowed? I believe maxdop is overridden with a value of 1 for indexes in non-enterprise.

Comment: I don't know but it's what you said in the question. You could not use wp_shoisactive to see the CPU time consumed by the index build. This should 99% coincide with the total time elapsed. This proves that it's a single threaded process that is almost fully CPU bound.

Comment: Do you have an alternative command name for "wp_shoisactive", I am not seeing it as an actual table.  Is it possibly the 3rd party util by Adam Machanic? I'd like to use a native query if possible.

Comment: not sure, is sp_who2 enough? otherwise youll have to google for some random "currently running queries" script

Comment: I havn't seen anything abnormal. I'm wondering if this is normal behavior and limitation with standard sql.